# Crystal Report Blank Space Issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with IFieldObjects what i need is if those fields have empty on null values i need to suppress them and remove the blank space from report.how can i remove this blank space.even though i suppress them the blank space is still there

Comment: I noticed this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343275/crystal-reports-hiding-columns . Why not accept an answer on this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly remove the space that a report field took up. You can, however, massage it in a few different ways to get it to behave that way.

Option 1: Add the field to a new report section all by itself and conditionally suppress that whole section depending on the value of the field. This will cause the section to not be printed, white space and all.

Option 2: Create one formula that builds up a long string of the field values that you're trying to print, including newlines and other formatting. If one of the fields is null, simply just omit it from the output string. Once you put the formula on the report, you can set it to "Can Grow" and it'll just take up as much space as it will need on the page.

I'll update if I think of any more.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the section's Suppress if Blank setting.