# Crystal Reports Hiding Columns

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with several columns.i need to hide a column and remove the blank space based on a condition.currently what i have done is.i have dragged and dropped the fields inside TextObject and tick the "Suppress Embedded Blank Field Lines" and "Can Grow".it'll hide the detail field and also remove the blank space but the issue is header is still visible.

condition to hide a column is if the field data is null or empty

Comment: not sure if i understand... is the report only returning a single row?  if all the rows shouldn't show that column, then don't even add the column.  but if one row out of 100 has the column then you need the header.  right?

Comment: not a single row.what i mean is in a single column if any row does'nt contain data that column should be hidden and the space for that column should be removed.

Comment: i understand that part but say you have 2 rows.  one row the column should be removed and the other row the column shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a formula for your conditionally displaying column heading. Something like:

```
SomeFieldLabel:

If DistinctCount({@SomeField}) > 0 Then "The Column Label"
```

or

```
If Not IsNull({@SomeField}) And {@SomeField} <> "" Then "The Column Label"
```

Then create a text object with {@SomeFieldLabel} and all your other labels, and select **Suppress Embedded Blank Field Lines**.

You may need to experiment to find the right condition – one which evaluates to True whenever the field is present in your detail records, and False the rest of the time.