# Auto adjust column size, position if some columns null

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting, crystal-reports-xi

I have a simple report with about 20 columns. Some of these columns might be empty. Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Check if a column is empty.
2. If it is empty, then readjust the position and size of rest of the columns
   to fill up the gap.
3. Repeat steps 1-2 for every column.

I have some ideas of where to start with but not sure how to move forward.
I can check if a column is [empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7380370/804503) by :

```
If DistinctCount({@SomeField}) > 0
```

I also know that the width and position can be changed by the formatting formulas. But how do I put this together? That is, what logic would run to check and expand the columns and where do I put this logic? Should I be using global variables?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Note: I am using Crystal Report XI

Comment: The columns you mean to be empty - are the empty in the whole table or are the empty when the report is generated and some parameters made some columns empty?

Comment: The parameter value is making them empty. Depending on the parameters being sent, some columns are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
Global booleanVar col1Empty := True;
Global booleanVar col2Empty := True;
...
if not IsNull({dbtable.col1}) then
  col1Empty := False;
if not IsNull({dbtable.col2}) then
  col2Empty := False;
```

Then use this global variables in suppres formulas.

Then count how many are not empty can calculate the average column width.